# Is there a technical word for the circuit that a relay turns on

Tags: relay

Is there a technical word for the circuit that a relay turns on?  In this case the circuit on the right side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo1JVW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A Load perhaps ?

Comment: @Mike and the left side is called the "control" circuit?

Comment: 'Load' or 'controlled circuit', depending on what your point of view is. You can call the other circuit the 'control circuit' or the '(relay) driver'.

Comment: I use the term "switched circuit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *The Load.*

The circuit that is 'powered' or 'controlled' by another component or circuit is often referred to simply as **the load** of the circuit.

It is referred to as a load as it 'loads down' the power supply, just as you would be loaded down should you be carrying something - the greater the load, the slower you will move, much like in a circuit, the bigger the load, the 'slower' current will flow.
If there was too little load a person would be able to run quicker and without common sense / ability to feel pain your body would start to break down, much like a power supply could burn out if too much power is drawn from it!